# sed with & in variable

Tags: variables, sed

I would like to search and replace with sed and replace with something in a variable which is containing some specials symbols like `&`.

For example I done something like that:

```
sed "s|http://.*|http://$URL|"
```

where `URL=1.1.1.1/login.php?user=admin&pass=password`. I thinks it became a problem because I use `?` and `&` in my variable.

How can I do my search and replace?

Answer (score 2):

```
URL="1.1.1.1/login.php?user=admin&pass=password"
URL=$(echo "$URL" | sed 's/&/\\&/')    # substitute to escape the ampersand
echo "$OTHER" | sed "s|http://.*|http://$URL|"
```

Answer (score 1):

`?` in the substitution is not a problem. `&` needs to be escaped as `\&`.

Comment: yes i know.
But I can"t add \ in my variable (or I don't know how to do it with another regexp).

Comment: What variable are you talking about? If you want to escape \, you have to do it like this \\.

Comment: he probably means the URL is dynamically generated and he can't add the backslash manually. extra routine need to be coded to escape & programmatically.

Comment: ... Couldn't you just use sed to replace it?

Answer (score 1):

The following worked for me (in a bash script):

```
URL="1.1.1.1/login.php?user=admin\\&pass=password"

echo "http://something" | sed -e "s|http://.*|http://$URL|"
```

The output was:

```
http://1.1.1.1/login.php?user=admin&pass=password
```

Comment: Hmm, I think you're right, but I'll have to come back to this twist, it's getting late.

Answer (score 1):

use awk

```
URL="1.1.1.1/login.php?user=admin&pass=password"
awk -vurl="$URL" '/http:\/\//{  gsub("http://" , "http://"url) }1' file
```

but are you really sure you just want to substitute http:// ??

Comment: awk treats a replacement string with an ampersand the same as sed does.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ URL="1.1.1.1/login.php?user=admin&pass=password"
$ echo "http://abcd" | sed -e "\|http://.*|c$URL"
1.1.1.1/login.php?user=admin&pass=password
```